# Change Rows to Columns and Group By

Tags: r, dataframe, spread

I have a relatively large DF and now need a way to make columns out of rows.

My DF looks like this:

```
AID FNAME FVALUE
1   A     10
1   B     12
1   C     16
2   A     10
2   E     4
3   F     10
3   G     13
```

and so on. Not all rows have all characteristics. So I like to have a final output like this:

```
AID A B C D E F G H 
1   10 12 16 NULL NULL NULL NULL
2   10 NULL NULL NULL 4 NULL NULL NULL
3   NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL 10 13 NULL
```

I have tried it with spread:

```
wide_DF <- unite_DF %>% spread(FNAME, FVALUE)
```

but I get the error:

> Error: Each row of output must be identified by a unique combination of keys.

Also I tried it to group the data and insert a new unique column:

```
unite_DF  %>% group_by(AID) %>% mutate(ind = row_number()) %>% spread(FNAME, FVALUE) %>% select(Name, Value)
```

But here I also get the same error. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

It seems you're looking for `reshape`:

```
AID <- c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3)
FNAME <- c("A", "B", "C", "A", "E", "F", "G")
FVALUE <- c(10, 12, 16, 10, 4, 10, 13)

df <- data.frame(AID, FNAME, FVALUE)

df_wide <- reshape(df, direction = "wide", idvar = "AID", v.names = "FVALUE", timevar = "FNAME")
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `spread` after converting the 'FNAME' to `factor` with `levels` specified and in the `spread`, use `drop = FALSE` to avoid dropping columns with no combinations

```
library(tidyverse)
unite_DF %>% 
  mutate(FNAME = factor(FNAME, levels = LETTERS[1:8])) %>% 
  spread(FNAME, FVALUE, drop = FALSE)
#   AID  A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H
#1   1 10 12 16 NA NA NA NA NA
#2   2 10 NA NA NA  4 NA NA NA
#3   3 NA NA NA NA NA 10 13 NA
```

#### data

```
unite_DF <- structure(list(AID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), FNAME = c("A", 
"B", "C", "A", "E", "F", "G"), FVALUE = c(10L, 12L, 16L, 10L, 
4L, 10L, 13L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

Comment: When I use this I get the error: Error in rep.int(rep.int(seq_len(nx), rep.int(rep.fac, nx)), orep) : invalid 'times' value

Comment: @Tim1234  I showed the data used along with output.  No error on my side

Comment: Yes your right. I think the problem is still R and R's maximum vector length  2^31-1. My total DF is to big.

Comment: @Tim1234  it this doesn't work, then `reshape` based `base R` wouldn't work either

Comment: Yes. Thanks man. I vote for your answer because with the sample df it works.